# Compare input value from screen in SQLDF where clause

Tags: r, variables, shiny, sqldf

I am new to `Shiny` and `R` both. I am trying to capture input value from `Shiny UI` part and based on the value, I am filtering the records from dataframe. I am using this code:

```
dat <- sqldf("select * from dat where CMPNT_NM = 'input$Compound'")
```

It's not returning any rows, just column name is coming. If I give any hardcoded value like `mP`, then it's running perfectly.

Any idea if I am doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would not have guessed that `CMPNT_NM = 'input$Compound'` would have delivered the right message to the SQL driver. Is that really a valid value in the database column's entries? It looks more like R code which I would not expect to be residing in the database.

Comment: Thanks Bonde!Yes, this is R code. I am receiving the compund name from user interface (ui.R). I don't want to pass any hard code value.   I am receiving the value from the following code:  output$choose_Compound <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Compound", "Compound_List", as.list(Compound2))
  })               And then I am filtering the record from dataframe  with user input value. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Piyush

Comment: output$choose_Compound <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Compound", "Compound_List", as.list(Compound2))
  })
I am trying to pass user input value in sqlquery.

Answer (score 0):

To get interpretation of something passed as an R value you should use a function that will ... evaluate it. Try:

```
dat <- sqldf( paste0( "select * from dat where CMPNT_NM = ", input$Compound) )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked very closely. But not 100%. Actually its giving following message :----> 

 "Error: RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such column: Insulin)".      

Actually its taking the value of "input$Compound"  as column name. We want to take this value as data value of column "CMPNT_NM"

Comment: I want to do like CMPNT_NM='mP' but I want to pass the value of "CMPNT_NM" from "input$Compound".

Comment: Hi Bond,

Thanks a lot for your help. This gives a nice help to proceed. I used the below line and it resolved the problem. I used "fn$sqldf"  ======>

dat <- fn$sqldf( paste0( "select * from dat where CMPNT_NM = '$test1'") ) . 

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: dat <- fn$sqldf( paste0( "select * from dat where CMPNT_NM = '$test1'") )    --- Worked fine for this issue.

Comment: `paste` is not needed: `fn$sqldf("select * from dat where COMPNT_NM = '$test' ")` is sufficient.

Comment: I hope I'm correct in thinking that the `paste` is not needed but only because he is using `pkg:gsubfn`. The original question did not reference that package, and that is why I am leaving my answer as it was. I think it is still needed if `fn$...` is not used.

Comment: The question referenced sqldf and sqldf automatically pulls in gsubfn.  Read the sqldf where examples are shown.

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer. Was it incorrect? My question to G.Grothendieck was not directly answered. (I do understand that fn$sqldf(...) would have succeeded because gsubfn is loaded when sqldf is loaded.)